# Faster way to evaluate 30+ If Then expressions in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I am looking to evaluate a cell value against 30 possible If Then conditions evaluated in binary (if x then y, if a then b with no duplicate values).

If cell (a, 35) is equal to any of those 30 values, cell (b,35) on a different sheet will need to be overwritten with a new value.

Running 30+ If Then pairs per line on the spreadsheet seems needlessly slow but I'm unfamiliar with any faster way to link data pairs for these purposes.  Any suggestions are v. appreciated!

Comment: Would a `Select Case` block work?

Comment: Case statements...  It will drop out after it hits the case that is a match.  Put the most likely(if there is any) at the top.

Comment: If you can show some sample data, perhaps you could use `Vlookup` or `Index/Match` instead?

Comment: (A sample data table/sheet would be great - I was just saying, it's *incredibly* rare (in my experience) to actually need `If()` statements with more than say 6 arguments.  There's most likely another way to tackle this, and seeing how your data is laid out and what you expect, helps in determining what we could do.)

Comment: as a small first step: if the cells to check are not in order (so you can't use lookup-functions like `MATCH`), then you can use `INDEX` + `CHOOSE` for up to 254 elements like this: (asuming `B1:C1,G2:H2,D8:E8,K12:L12` has the true/false part to the left and the output to the right) `{=INDEX((C1,E8,H2,L12),1,1,MIN(IF(CHOOSE(ROW(1:4),B1,D8,G2,K12),ROW(1:4))))}` just make sure that `INDEX` and `CHOOSE` get the same order... now index will output the first value of `C1,E8,H2,L12` where the parter (`B1,D8,G2,K12`) is true ;)